# AWS Calculator - How reserved instance cost gets calculated?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am using AWS calculator - http://calculator.s3.amazonaws.com/index.html.

When I chose reserve instances, in the estimate of monthly bill tab, I get "Total One-Time Payment" value.

Suppose, I have 3 servers cost to calculate. If I calculate the monthly cost of 3 servers and each server considered with 1 yr heavy reserve instance, then what the "Total One-Time Payment" value implies?

Whether that value is complete year upfront cost or 1 year upfront cost divided by 12?

Please help me understand.

Regards,

Chandan

Answer (score 0):

It is the complete year upfront cost, meaning that you pay that amount only once at the beginning. After that you only pay for the compute time each month (the amount on the row labeled "Compute:").

Comment: Thanks David for sharing your knowledge.